# Observable does not subscribe on page refresh, unless delay() is added

Tags: angular, rxjs, page-refresh, subscribe

I have an Angular app where I get some QueryParams from the URL and I use them to call a service.

On direct access, the page loads fine, but if I refresh the page an inner `subscribe()` method is not triggered. If I add a delay of 1 second to the subscribe method fetching the queryParams, I can see in the console that the "[WDS] Live Reloading enabled" message gets triggered before my code and the inner subscribe is called properly.

It seems somehow a timing issue.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap
    .pipe(
      delay(1000)  // <- Without this, the subscribe inside manageTaskState is not called
    )
    .subscribe(params => {
      // ...

      this.manageTaskState(params);
    });
  }

private manageTaskState(params: ParamMap) { 
    if (this.isExpired(Date.parse(this.expirationDate))) {
      this.taskState = TaskState.EXPIRED;
      // ...
    } else {
      this.orderService.getTaskStatus(ProductType[this.productType], partnerNr, this.expirationDate)
      .pipe(
        withLatestFrom(this.partnerService.getByPartnerNr(partnerNr)),
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
      )
      .subscribe({
        // It does not reach here on page refresh
        next: ([status, partner]) => {
          if (status.size > 0) {
            this.taskState = TaskState.ALREADY_SUBMITTED;
            // ...
          } else {
            this.loadComponent(this.productType);
          }
        },
        error: (e) => console.error(e)
      });
    }
```

---

**UPDATE**

After further investigation, the `orderService.getTaskStatus` call is triggered and I get the response from the server (looking at the Network Tab in DevTools), but the code inside the `subscribe` is never hit.

Below the other methods involved:

```
// From partnerService.ts
  get(): Observable<Partner[]> {

      // This method gets called elsewhere, hence 
      // the ReplaySubject is created

      if (!this.partners$) {
        this.partners$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
      }

      this.getRoot()
        .pipe(
          switchMap(root => super.getCall(root.getLink('all'))),
          map(result => {
            return result.partners.map(p => new Partner(p));
          })
        )
        .subscribe({
          next: partners => {
            return this.partners$.next(partners);
          },
          error: error => this.partners$.error(error)
        });

    return this.partners$.asObservable();
  }

  getByPartnerNr(partnerNr: string): Observable<Partner> {
    return this.get().pipe(
      map(partner => {
        return partner.find(p => partnerNr === p.partnerNr);
      })
    );
  }
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

Changing `withLatestFrom` with `CombineLatest` solves the issue. It seems due to the timing when the second observable emits. This is though curious, as `WithLatestFrom`, [according to the docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/withlatestfrom), should work fine no matter if it is faster or slower than the source observable.

```
combineLatest([this.orderService.getTaskStatus(ProductType[this.productType], partnerNr, this.expirationDate),
      this.partnerService.getByPartnerNr(partnerNr)])
      .subscribe({
        // I can access here also on page refresh
});
```

Comment: from what you describe, the issue must lie in either `this.orderService.getTaskStatus` or `this.partnerService.getByPartnerNr`. Try replacing both function implementations with a simple `of` to see if that would work.

Comment: Is the refresh triggered by you (F5)  or by the LiveReload ?

Comment: I reload the page  manually (F5).

Comment: @ggradnig The issue seems to be related to the `getByPartnerNr` method (good hint using of()). However I see that the network call is correctly triggered by the `orderService.getTaskStatus` method. Simply the code inside subscribe is not called.

Answer (score 0):

> Changing withLatestFrom with CombineLatest solves the issue.

As far as I can tell, if this works, it means that `this.partnerService.getByPartnerNr(partnerNr)` emits **before** `this.orderService.getTaskStatus` does.

This is what the [source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/withLatestFrom.ts#L135) tells us:

```js
_next(value: T) {
  if (this.toRespond.length === 0) { // If all the observables provided to `withLatestFrom` emitted at least once
    const args = [value, ...this.values];
    if (this.project) {
      this._tryProject(args);
    } else {
      this.destination.next(args);
    }
  }
}
```

where `toRespond` decreases as the provided observables emit:

```js
// Called when an `inner` observable emits
notifyNext(outerValue: T, innerValue: R,
            outerIndex: number, innerIndex: number,
            innerSub: InnerSubscriber<T, R>): void {
  this.values[outerIndex] = innerValue;
  const toRespond = this.toRespond;
  if (toRespond.length > 0) {
    const found = toRespond.indexOf(outerIndex);
    if (found !== -1) {
      toRespond.splice(found, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

[Source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/withLatestFrom.ts#L117-L128)

So, `withLatestFrom` might not work because the provided observables do not emit at **least once** before the source emits.

In contrast to `combineLatest` which emits for the **first time** when **all** the provided observables would have emitted at least once. After that, it would emit every time one observable emits a new value.

Comment: However looking at the second example from the docs (link is in my question), the observable inside the WithLatestFrom emits 4 seconds after the source and still it works fine. Here the Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-gigsdv?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100

Comment: Could you elaborate? As far as I can tell, the SB demo illustrates what I've said in my answer(_provided observables do not emit at least once before the source emits_). It is also explained [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/rxjs-operators-for-dummies-forkjoin-zip-combinelatest-withlatestfrom#toc-withlatestfrom-the-master-slave-operator) very well.

Comment: You are right. Form the RxJs website example I interpreted the behaviour differently, but the website you provided explain it well!